# Mootools when to use Function.prototype.bind

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a very basic question that I could not find an answer for, I did check the mootools website, but I did not yet fully grasp the concept:

In mootools you have a function .bind() and it can supposedly be used as follows:

```
function customFunction () {
    this.setStyle('color','blue');
}

var boundFunction = customFunction.bind(myElement);
boundFunction(); //Now the color of the element is changed to red

// To show how bind works the following example:
var myBoundFunction = myFunction.bind(anyVar);
// is roughly equivalent with
var myBoundFunction = function(){
    return myFunction.call(this);
};
```

But why not just do it this way?

```
function customFunction (parameter) {
    parameter.setStyle('color','blue');
}

customFunction(myElement);
```

This seems more efficient?

My big question is:
Where would it be a good practise to use .bind(), and why would it be?

Comment: it should be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Flag you question - and post my comment as message for moderators

Comment: I don't think this should be moved to Codereview. CR has today just 2 questions tagged with Mootools, SO is the best place for answering this question.

Comment: @Sergio - maybe you are right than. I thought its more about javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind is useful when passing a method as a callback argument. Say we have the following `user` object:

```
function User(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
User.prototype.sayHi = function() {
    console.log("Hi, my name is "+this.name);
}

var user = new User("John");
```

And now we'd like to invoke its `sayHi` method when somebody clicks on some div element. We could attempt to do this:

```
$('userDiv').addEvent('click', user.sayHi);
```

But this will not work as we're only passing the `sayHi` function itself, but its context (the value of `this`) will be lost, and the function will print `"Hi, my name is undefined"`.

To keep the context, we could instead do:

```
$('userDiv').addEvent('click', function() { user.sayHi(); });
```

But its much simpler to attach the context with a `bind`:

```
$('userDiv').addEvent('click', user.sayHi.bind(user));
```

Comment: also, `Function.prototype.bind` accepts arguments in addition to scope, which allows you to pass extra data along with the invocation. it can also be useful when you are hooking into native Type methods, eg. `Array.prototype.shift.bind(this.todos)`. if you use strict, you can do `window.addEvent('domready', function(){ this.alert('hi'); }.bind(this));` to retain `this` as defined and pointing to the global object etc etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind